# attempting to create a button which runs a script however the H1 and button disappear onClick

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I hope you can read my code, I have an XML file on my localhost and I would like it to pull the title and year from that file (it currently has Title, Year, Artist, Price, and Country) while maintaining the H1 and button on the page.

The H1 text and button disappear onClick and I would like it to remain on the same page as the results.

```
  <h1>Show the Album list</h1>  
   <script>  
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  

   xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);  
   xmlhttp.send();  
   xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;  
   function CdCatalog()  
    {
       document.write("<table border='1'><th>TITLE</th><th>YEAR</th>");
       var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");  
       for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
   document.write("<tr><td>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</td><td>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
       document.write("</table>");
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: `new XMLHttpRequest()` <-- long time no see (I have been using jQuery for awhile now)

Comment: Instead of using `document.write`, you should probably use `document.body.innerHTML += "<td>blah</td>"`

Comment: Thanks Derek, I haven't learned that yet but I will take a look at some tutorials.

Comment: You can take a look at [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/AHZ4C/). It's not that difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `document.write` for a button's click event, which is after the document's been closed...which means it overwrites everything. Since your page is simple and only has an `<h1>` and button, it looks like only those things are being hidden, but it would be everything on the page (if you had more).

The solution is to use `.appendChild` and/or `.innerHTML` to add the content dynamically. I'll provide a solution in a minute :)

**UPDATE**:

Since you're using tables, you might as well use the native methods `.insertRow` and `.insertCell` that make table creation much easier. Here's an example of what you could use overall:

```
function CdCatalog(xmlDoc) {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var thead = table.createTHead();    // Where "header" rows go
    // `insertRow` creates a <tr> element and appends it to `thead` automatically, returning the element
    var tr = thead.insertRow(-1);
    var td = document.createElement("th");  // No special method for creating "th" elements
    td.innerHTML = "TITLE";  // Set its inner content
    tr.appendChild(th);  // Add it to the row (which is in the header)
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = "YEAR";
    tr.appendChild(td);

    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    // "tbody" is where a table's content goes, whether you do this explicitly or not
    var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tr = tbody.insertRow(-1);
        // `insertCell` creates a <td> element and appends it to `tr` automatically, returning the element
        td = tr.insertCell(-1);
        td.innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        td = tr.insertCell(-1);
        td.innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    // Actually add the table to the DOM (the <body> element in this case)...you can specify where else to put it
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}

// Make sure DOM is ready for manipulation
window.onload = function () {
    var btn = document.getElementById("button_id");  // Whatever your button is
    // Bind the "click" event for the button
    btn.onclick = function () {
        // Make your AJAX request
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        // Pass the result to the function, instead of making everything global and sharing
        CdCatalog(xmlDoc);
    };
};
```

And unless I'm mistaken, you can't nest `<td>` inside of `<table>`...you must nest them in `<tr>`...which are nested in `<table>`

Comment: Woah that is awesome. You guys are awesome. I am going to break this down and find out how it works. Thanks for the help. Everyone on here is great.

Comment: @FelipeGonzales No problem. I just updated and added comments, so hopefully it helps you understand a little better. Let us know if you need more help!

Comment: that is incredible you can pull that together so quickly, if you could only see me writing the code earlier. It was like watching my grandmother type. thanks again

Comment: @FelipeGonzales Hahahaha...grandma! Well I'm sure you can outcode us in a different language. It's just something I, and other people on here, work with often.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write`. It will remove everything you have inside the tag since the document is closed. Do this instead:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<td>blah</td>"

-or-

var td = document.createElement("td");
td.innerHTML = "blah"
document.querySelector("table").appendChild(td);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/AHZ4C/

Comment: Thanks Derek, I took a look at your link and it helps a lot. I am slowly getting this.